# from pandas_datareader import DataReader, get_quote_yahoo

Tags: jupyter-lab, anaconda3

I want to retrieve the market capitalization on yahoo finance.but i get a problem.

here's the name of the error i'm getting : ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'pandas_datareader'[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/m0nmx.png)

I tried this code:

from pandas_datareader import DataReader, get_quote_yahoo.

I was expecting this when i run the code